# Table insertion is without any order in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

i have developed a system in asp.net using entity framework. all other tables are doing fine but when i insert data in some tables, it doesn't insert in ascending order. what could be the problem?? 
Following is how data is inserted:

```
1
10
11
12
13
2
21
22
23
24
25
3
31
32
4
5
6
7
```

P.S Please dont tell me about data retrieval through order by clause. I am asking about insertion order.

Comment: Let me guess. It is a string field? (By the way, when you insert there is no order to respect, data is inserted as it reaches the database)

Comment: its type is varchar. is there any solution to make it right??

Comment: If this column should contain only numbers then the right decision is to change the column to be numeric not varchar

Comment: Insertion order is irrelevant (except if a column has a continuously increasing default value reflecting this order such as datetime or identity) as it doesn't necessarily equate to storage order nor does storage order equate to select order.

Comment: thanks. i'll change its datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inherent order in SQL databases. When you run a select, directly or through Entity Framework (EF), your DB is free to return the rows in any order that it finds optimal for data retrieval.

To address issues that may happen because of such lack of order SQL supplies `ORDER BY` clause, which controls the order in which the retrieved information is returned to you. In EF this corresponds to the `OrderBy` method:

```
var results = db.MyTable.OrderBy(row => row.SomeField);
```

In your specific case, however, it appears that you are inserting numeric data into a character-based field. When this happens, the data is sorted *lexicographically* (i.e. like words in a dictionary) which produces the order that you see. To maintain the intended order use the proper data type for your column: if the column is numeric, use one of many numeric SQL types for it.